# QGIS and QQuake for earthquakes

Tags: qgis

I installed [QQUake plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qquake/) and I got earthquake points but all of them are in 2D X,Y.
Also I tried to import list of earthquake's and used Z axis for depth but again it comes as 2D X,Y.

So question is is there a way to get depth points in 3D Map view or similar?

Idea is to create 3D view map with terrain (which I have) and earthquakes points (which I have) where earthquake points are shown in corresponding depth which I can not achieve.

This is example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: If you have Z-values in the attribute table you could use `Set Z value` from processing toolbox

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I did try it.  please see this print screen https://i.ibb.co/LkK0x9q/Z-Value.jpg.
Still after that points are on same level 0m.
I did google this but nothing specific I didnt find.

Comment: hi @miro. Did you activated the 3D style for the earthquakes point layer?

Comment: HI I have resolved this.
Point is that my depth points were in km and I had to convert them to meters so for example -1.2km I changed to -1200. this works also as Z value and abosulte.